# Smarty remove trailing comma in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, smarty, trim

I have the following loop in smarty:

```
{foreach from=$method.params key=name item=type}
    <i style="font-weight: normal;">{$type}</i> {$name},
{/foreach}
```

What is the best way to remove the trailing comma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer Twig over Smarty so I'm working from the docs, but here's my stab:

```
{assign var="comma" value=""}
{foreach from=$method.params key=name item=type}
    {$comma}<i style="font-weight: normal;">{$type}</i> {$name}
    {assign var="comma" value=", "}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it also this way:

```
{foreach from=$method.params key=name item=type name=myloop}
    <i style="font-weight: normal;">{$type}</i> {$name}
    {if not $smarty.foreach.myloop.last}, {/if}
{/foreach}
```

You also didn't mentioned what Smarty version you use. If you use Smarty 3 (which you should use if it's your choice you should rather use Smarty 3 `foreach` style and not Smarty 2 foreach style).

**EDIT**

As you mentioned you use Smarty 3, you should rather use Smarty 3 `foreach` syntax this way:

```
{foreach $method.params as $name => $type}
    <i style="font-weight: normal;">{$type}</i> {$name}
    {if not $type@last}, {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Ahh, cool! I like that syntax much better than `from` and `item`